# Is the boundary of a convex set differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

I figured that a convex set can have at most sharp corners like in $|x|$ but not cusps, and I'm wondering if the sharp corners are measure zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the points of non differentiability form a negligible set.

Suppose you have a convex set with nonempty interior, otherwise it is a degenerate case in which the convex set coincides with its boundary. Then you can partition its boundary in a finite number of pieces, such that each piece can be viewed as a graph of a convex function, with respect to a suitable coordinate system (for instance consider the projection on the coordinate hyperplanes). Now you can conclude use the following two facts:

1) Every convex function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb R^m$, with $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ convex, is locally Lipschitz (I think this fact can be found in any book on convex analysis).

2) By [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) any Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Actually [Alexandrov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_theorem) implies the stronger result that a convex function has a *second order* expansion (i.e. Taylor expansion up to second derivatives) almost everywhere.